# How to Compute f(x) for a=1 and various values of the parameter b on the interval 0<x<3

Tags: matlab

I tried using below codes with no luck

```
f = 0;
a = 1;
b = [1 2 3.5];

for x = 0:3
  f = (a * b * x).^(b-1)*exp(-a*x.^b);
end 

disp (f);
```

Comment: Please add any attempts and relevant code. That will allow the community to work along the approach you're going for and assist you in constructing an appropriate solution.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 basically Im trying to compute fx for a(1) against all values of B via loop through the interval 0<x<3

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the domain is `x` and the comparison parameter is `b` we can loop through the values of `b` to create three distinct vectors for which the function, `f` is plotted for. Here the value of `b` is swapped on each iteration of the for-loop. The resultant end up being `f` with 3 rows by 4 columns where the columns correspond to the x-values/domain and the rows correspond to the value of parameter, `b`.

[image: Output Plot/Results]

```
x = (0:3);
a = 1;
B = [1 2 3.5];

for Parameter_Index = 1: length(B)
    b = B(Parameter_Index);
    f(Parameter_Index,:) = (a.*b.*x).^(b-1).*exp(-a.*x.^b);
end

plot(x,f(1,:),x,f(2,:),x,f(3,:));
xlabel("x"); ylabel("f(x)");
legend("B = " + num2str(B(1)),"B = " + num2str(B(2)),"B = " + num2str(B(3)));
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**